# Telegram and VK theme button animation

Tags: flutter, animation, button, themes

Tell me how to animate the theme switch button?  like in telegrams, vk, EXACTLY ANIMATION BUTTONS, now I just have two icons light and dark change without any animation, I would like with beautiful animation, I will be grateful, thanks)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897816/how-to-add-animation-for-theme-switching-in-flutter) is your answer , Check it .

Comment: also check [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher) plugin.