# Flutter Animated IconThemeData

Tags: flutter, animation, icons

Can `IconTheme` be combined with `AnimatedBuilder` to create an animated change to all descendent Icons in a flutter tree. This behaviour can be achieved with `TextStyles` via `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle`. Can it be done with `IconThemeData`.

```
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: someListener,
  builder: (context, child) => IconTheme(
    data: IconThemeData(
      color: ColorTween(
        begin: Colors.Blue, 
        end: Colors.Red).animate(someListener).value,
     ),
     child: child,
  ),
  child: List(
    children: [
      // list of icons
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897816/how-to-add-animation-for-theme-switching-in-flutter

Comment: That's broadly speaking what I wrote is it not?